# Offline mobile application for XAF application

Tags: mobile, devexpress, offline, xaf

Devexpress has lately intoduced XAF mobile UI but it does not support offline capabilities.

I am wondering what would be a solution for this scenario:
There is a Middlte Tier Web application, working with WCF. I need a mobile app that is able to work offline and then when the user goes online the data should be synced to the database.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such technology that provides such behaviour out of the box. Therefore you need to role your own